Pyarrow: How to join larger than memory datasets and create new columns?
I have a larger than memory datasets. I can read them using pyarrow dataset API, but unable to join without triggering in memory join. The join result is supposed to be larger than memory as well. How can I force pyarrow to be 'Lazy'? Also, how to create a new columns by row wise summing to columns. Basically, this is how it works in duckdb :
import duckdb

import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd

rt = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'passenger_count':[0,1,2,3,4]*5,'rand':[5,3,2,1,2]*5}),
                          schema=pa.schema([('passenger_count',pa.int8()),('rand',pa.int8())]))
duckdb.sql("""
copy 
(
    select *,a.trip_distance + b.rand as test
    from read_parquet('Z:/nyc_hive/yr=2009/*/*parquet',hive_partitioning=True) a 
    inner join rt b
    on a.passenger_count = b.passenger_count
)
TO 'nyc_duck' (FORMAT PARQUET, PARTITION_BY (yr, month));
""")

How to replicate this is pyarrow?
What I've tried, but results in out of memory error:
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
# Create a PyArrow dataset for each table
table_a_dataset = ds.dataset('Z:/a77980db-7f0a-41b0-94ff-0913c98e183b/nyc_hive/yr=2009/', format='parquet')
j = table_a_dataset.join(rt,'passenger_count') #triggers the join
#what i want:
# j = table1.join(table2).project(col('a') + col('b')) # dont trigger
# j.write(XYZ.parquet) # now it triggers the data pull, join and write. never OOMing


I've not used pyarrow too much - but from what I can see, it doesn't seem like it's supported? Dataset.join() returns an InMemoryDataset

@jqurious yep, thats what I could gather as well. Isn't duckdb using arrow as well in backend for processing parquets?

Not that I am aware of. duckdb has its own implementations: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/blob/main/extension/parquet/parquet_reader.cpp
